# Object Event Listbox Gone

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Say I create a new vb project an I have the toolbox of objects to use for it. If I create a button and double click on it, I will be redirected into the button's event code. At the top of the window (of the visible code) there is a dropdown bar which allows me to select other event listeners such as, "mouse over", "hover", "Keydown", or something like "LostFocus". I somehow lost this feature and it has made programming harder for me. Could someone please explain how to bring back this feature?

Thanks!

-Guest

Comment: Is there a question in our near future?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sory, I'll edit, somethign wierd happened with my network then

Comment: Since this is a duplicate, is there anyway I can delete this thread?

Comment: No harm or shame in leaving it